# How to replace a null value in a calculated field in a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace a null value in a calculated column with 0 in a SQL Server query.

This my query.

```
SELECT   
    Scenario, sum_amount + sum_cash + sum_tips AS total_earned 
FROM
    Cash_Scenario 
WHERE 
    scenario_Id = 5
```

I tried

```
SELECT   
    Scenario, sum_amount + sum_cash + sum_tips  AS total_earned,
    ISNULL(total_earned, 0) 
FROM
    Cash_Scenario 
WHERE
    scenario_Id = 5
```

But I am getting an error:

> Invalid column name 'total_earned' error.

Essentially I want to return 0, if the total_earned value is null.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a big fan of using the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` rather than the bespoke `ISNULL()` for this operation -- unless there is a compelling reason to use `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT Scenario,
       (COALESCE(sum_amount, 0) + COALESCE(sum_cash, 0) + COALESCE(sum_tips, 0)
       ) AS total_earned 
FROM Cash_Scenario 
WHERE scenario_Id = 5;
```

And, just for fun, you could do:

```
SELECT Scenario, x.total_earned 
FROM Cash_Scenario s CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(x) as total_earned
      FROM (VALUES (sum_amount), (sum_cash), (sum_tips)) v(x)
     ) x
WHERE scenario_Id = 5;
```

I am the first to admit that `APPLY`, though, is *not* ANSI standard.  Sometimes, though, it is just fun to find arcane but efficient ways to do something.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
SELECT Scenario, ISNULL(sum_amount,0) + ISNULL(sum_cash,0) + ISNULL(sum_tips,0) AS total_earned
FROM Cash_Scenario Where scenario_Id = 5
```

Comment: For anyone confused, `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard and `ISNULL` is not, so I'd rather go with the other answer